# Add an object into JSON array with Go

Tags: json, go

I've got a JSON file called '*books.json*' looking like this:

```
{"Books":
    [
    ]
}
```

and I'd like to add something like this into the array using Go:

```
{
    "Title": "Lord of the Rings",
    "Author: "J. R. Tolkien",
    "Language: "English"
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I tried several tutorials, This one (https://dev.to/christalib/append-data-to-json-in-go-5gbj) seemed the most useful, but always reset my the json file.

Comment: BTW, your JSON representing a book is invalid.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed I got a typo in the "Language" part

Comment: Both Language and Author don't have closing quotation marks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a struct to hold your data:

```golang
type Book struct {
    Title    string `json:"Title"`
    Author   string `json:"Author"`
    Language string `json:"Language"`
}

type Library struct {
    Books []Book `json:"Books"`
}
```

2. Unmarshal existing JSON to the struct:

```golang
in := `{"Books": []}`
var library Library
json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &library)
```

3. Append a new `Book`:

```golang
newBook := Book{
    Title: "Lord of the Rings",
    Author: "J.R. Tolkien",
    Language: "English",
}
library.Books = append(library.Books, newBook)
```

4. Marshal back to JSON and check the result:

```golang
j, _ := json.Marshal(library)
fmt.Println(string(j))
```

Entire code on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/v24dKorFpK5